# iOS crash, can't symbolicate

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate

My crash log:

```
Application received signal SIGSEGV
(null)
(
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182ab02f4 <redacted> + 160
  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001942d40e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
  2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182ab0218 <redacted> + 0
  3   yixia                               0x429496857fc2 _ZN15CTXAppidConvert17IsConnectionAppIdEPKc + 149220
  4   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x0000000194b0094c _sigtramp + 52
  5   yixia                               0x42949679ff82 yixia + 485740
  6   yixia                               0x4294967b8072 yixia + 584284
  7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000194925994 <redacted> + 24
  8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000194925954 <redacted> + 16
  9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000019492a20c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1608
  10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182a677f8 <redacted> + 12
  11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182a658a0 <redacted> + 1492
  12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001829912d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
  13  GraphicsServices                    0x000000018c1a76fc GSEventRunModal + 168
  14  UIKit                               0x0000000187556fac UIApplicationMain + 1488
  15  yixia                               0x4294967b8746 yixia + 586032
  16  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000194952a08 <redacted> + 4
)

dSYM UUID: 220AF59E-3467-377E-B8AE-DA048BA93DDC
CPU Type: arm64
Slide Address: 0x429496729616x
Binary Image: yixia
Base Address: 0x00000001000a8000
```

My `dSYM` file: [dSYM](https://github.com/Julyyq/CrasheddSYM).

I run `dwarfdump --arch=arm64 --lookup  0x429496857fc2 yixia.app.dSYM` and get the following result:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 File: yixia.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/yixia (arm64)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Looking up address: 0x0000429496739102 in .debug_info... not found.
Looking up address: 0x0000429496739102 in .debug_frame... not found.
```

I'm sure this code causes crash: [crash code](https://github.com/Julyyq/CrasheddSYM/blob/master/crash.m).

The app crashes after invoking `+ (NSData *)generateGIFWithImage:(UIImage *)image andStickers:(NSArray *)stickers small:(BOOL)small withShareType:(NSUInteger)shareType`, screenshot:

[image]

then my iPhone lost connection.

Comment: Please check you have added all libraries and framework properly

Comment: @AshokLondhe Why do you say this?

Comment: Sometimes application get crashes because of Library. if library is missing.

Comment: @AshokLondhe Doesn't Xcode show missing library errors before compiling?

Comment: Clean derived data from Organiser

Comment: inform me if you problem get solved...

Comment: @AshokLondhe Nope, the issue is still exist.

Comment: create new schema and try it again. please share your code

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
dwarfdump --arch=arm64 --lookup  0x429496857fc2 yixia.app.dSYM
```

With

```
atos -arch arm64 -o yixia.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/yixia 0x429496857fc2
```

Read [this blog (written in Chinese)](http://blog.csdn.net/u011303816/article/details/44041171)  for more.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
dwarfdump --arch=arm64 --lookup  0x429496857fc2 yixia.app.dSYM
```

to

```
dwarfdump --arch=arm64 --lookup  0x4294967AFFC2 yixia.app.dSYM
```

you need set `file-address` to `--lookup`，not stack-address.
see [this page](https://www.apteligent.com/technical-resource/symbolicating-an-ios-crash-report/?partner_code=GDC_so_symbolicateios)